# JSP function running every time page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, function, jsp, onload

I want to add an item to a shopping basket only the first time the user clicks "add to basket" however every time i refresh the page it adds it again.

Here is my code that adds the item to the basket

```
    <%
    String empty = request.getParameter("emptyBasket");
    if (empty!=null) {
        basket.clearBasket();
    }

    String item = request.getParameter("addItem"); %>

<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        if(localStorage.getItem("notFirstTime") == null) {
            <% basket.addItem(item); %>
            localStorage.setItem("notFirstTime", true);
        }
    }
</script>

<html>
<body> ....
```

As you can see I have tried using the window.onload method but it does not work for some reason. Let me know if you need to see any more code and i will update.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should get a better understand of how `JSP` pages work. All the `Java` code on these pages is compiled an executed before the page is loaded and converted to `HTML`, `JavaScript` or `CSS` code which means that `<% basket.addItem(item); %>` will always get executed.

Answer (score 1):

JSP runs on the server. JavaScript runs on the browser. Server-side code runs first on the server to generate the page. Then it sends it over the network to the browser where it runs JavaScript. `basket.addItem(item)` will always run as part of the page-generation process since it's server-side code.

You might want to consider cookies (for anonymous users) or the DB (for authenticated users) for storage of these values.

Comment: thank you for your reply, how would you suggest i do this instead?

Comment: @JamesMcCutcheon Cookies are commonly used for this task, particularly if the user is anonymous. If this operation is done by an authenticated user, you could just use the DB.